# Weird behavior of Django ORM

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm, django-queryset

I am using Django ORM to execute a complex query which looks something like this:

```
user_ids = MyLog.objects.values('user_id').annotate(
    last_configured=Max('configured')
).exclude(
    last_configured__lt=earlier_date
).filter(content_type_id=configuration_content_type).values_list('user_id', flat=True)
```

which evaluates to:

```
SELECT `customer_mylog`.`user_id`, MAX(`customer_mylog`.`configured`)
AS `last_configured` FROM `customer_mylog`
WHERE (`customer_mylog`.`content_type_id` = 654 )
GROUP BY `customer_mylog`.`user_id`
HAVING NOT (MAX(`customer_mylog`.`configured`) < 2014-04-19 20:22:38.729416 )
ORDER BY NULL
```

At this point, I am sure that the query is not executed yet unless I do something like `len(user_ids)` which I don't. I then modify it by doing something like this:

```
new_user_ids = User.objects.filter(pk__in=user_ids).exclude(date_joined__lt=earlier_date).exists()
```

which changes the original query to this:

```
SELECT `auth_user`.`id`, `auth_user`.`username`, `auth_user`.`first_name`, `auth_user`.`la 
st_name`, `auth_user`.`email`, `auth_user`.`password`, `auth_user`.`is_staff`, `auth_user`.` 
is_active`, `auth_user`.`is_superuser`, `auth_user`.`last_login`, `auth_user`.`date_joined`  
FROM `auth_user` WHERE (`auth_user`.`id` IN (SELECT U0.`user_id` FROM `customer_mylo 
g` U0 WHERE (U0.`content_type_id` = 654 ) GROUP BY U0.`user_id` HAVING NOT (MAX(U0.`configured`)  
< 2014-05-04 13:04:48.204187 ) ORDER BY NULL) AND NOT (`auth_user`.`date_joined` < 2014-05-0 
4 13:04:48 ))
```

If I execute the query by doing something like list(new_user_ids), it never finishes execution. It neither fails, nor gives any error messages.

So instead, I tried the following method and it worked perfectly somehow.

```
for user_id in user_ids:
    if User.objects.filter(pk=user_id).exclude(date_joined__lt=earlier_date).exists():
        new_user_ids.append(user_id)
```

Why would the previous method not work, although both are essentailly similar in what they are trying to do?

Comment: It will never evaluate unless you ask it to:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Comment: @petkostas I think I was not able to properly explain myself in the question. Please review it again.

Comment: If you try to evaluate it through len? what do you get?
As stated in the django documentation (regarding list):
`Be warned, though, that this could have a large memory overhead, because Django will load each element of the list into memory.`

Comment: Additionally try to run the queryset in a shell and check what happens.

Comment: @petkostas I have already tried that. It gets stuck forever. For instance, if I force query execution using `list(new_user_ids)` the query starts execution but never goes to completed. The other method that I posted works fine however.

Comment: How many results are we talking about? list() will load ALL results, the other method that works for you iterates one by one, that's an impact if we are talking about a huge result list.

Comment: @petkostas The table contains a lot of records but the result set that should be returned is about a 100. The thing is that why would a for loop work but the previous query won't on same data set with equivalent queries?

Comment: Try to evalute the user_ids before passing it to the queryset. From the output of your second query it seems it's not, does that work?

Comment: Also check this:
http://mattrobenolt.com/the-django-orm-and-subqueries/

Comment: @petkostas The thing is that the for loop method would result in the evaluation of the first query and hence it succeeds. I need to find the reason why the other method fails because the reasons are not obvious.

Comment: Running the SQL query raw on your DB, does it work?

Comment: Which DB and DB version do you use? Older MySQL versions are really not well optimized for complex subqueries.

Comment: @Etienne This problem occurred with version `5.5.37-0ubuntu0.12.04.1`.

Comment: @MohammadRafayAleem I think MySQL devs really optimized subqueries in 5.6 (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-nutshell.html and http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/subquery-optimization.html). You could try to add a `list()` around your subquery to test if it's a problem with MySQL subqueries optimization. It will trigger 2 queries without subquery instead of one with a subquery. If the result is a lot faster, that was the problem. In this case you have 2 solutions: keep the `list()` in your query or upgrade to 5.6.

Answer (score 2):

Django Querysets are not evaluated directly, in order to make the ORM evaluate them and Query the underlying Database you need to perform an actual action on them:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you're calling [`.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#exists) on one queryset, doing all the heavy lifting in the db and getting back a boolean, while the other you're `filter`ing and loading all into memory as full on Python objects.

Your last bit of code, the `exists()` check doesn't actually instantiate any objects, it only checks in the DB whether or not a user matches the query and stops, instead of generating a list of all the User objects

It takes way more time to instantiate all models over just counting to see whether it's possible to instantiate them.